# The task is being received but I do not receive a notification that it has been executed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery

The task is being received but I don't get a notification that it is executed I want to know if the task is running

import logging
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(**name**)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

```
@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def deneme(request):
    eta_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)
    result = add.apply_async((3,5),eta=eta_time, result=True)
    logger.info('Task %s succeeded in %s seconds: %s', result.task_id, result.result)
    
    return Response("Deneme")
```

the result i expected
[2023-05-04 14:09:14,515: INFO/MainProcess] Task challenge.task.add[f4a7a3dc-d774-41a3-8aa3-3a7e8f7895b2] succeeded in 0.0779999999795109s: 8